# Nav toolbar and side nav not coming in other components

Tags: html, angular, navigation, angular-router

I have searched for this question a lot but still unable to find the solution.

In my app, the after successful logging in the page shows the side nav and toolbar. When an item(component) is clicked in side nav, the respective component is displayed but toolbar does not and also side nav.

Here are the files I have written,

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="user_id !== undefined">
    <app-applayoutmodel></app-applayoutmodel>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts,

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras, ActivatedRoute , Params} from '@angular/router';
import * as globals from '../app/pages/models/myGlobals';
import { LoginService } from '../serviceProviders/loginservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  user_id: string = undefined;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private loginservice: LoginService ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      if ( this.router.url.length === 1) {
        this.user_id = undefined;
      } else {
      console.log('Url  ' + this.router.url);
      const urlParam = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams['property_id'];
      this.loginservice.user_id = urlParam;
      this.user_id = this.loginservice.user_id;
      }
      // subscribe to router event
    }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'applayout', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

applayoutmodel.component.html,

```
<div class="page">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
    <div>
    <button class="menuButton" mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <span class="companyName">YAANA</span>
    </div>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-sidenav-container class="sideContainer" fullscreen  autosize style="top: 80px !important;">
      <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" opened="false" class="sideNav">
        <mat-nav-list>
          <nav class="menuItems">
            <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
          </nav>
          <nav class="menuItems">
            <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
          </nav>
      </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
    </div>
```

applayoutmodel.component.ts,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-applayoutmodel',
  templateUrl: './applayoutmodel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./applayoutmodel.component.scss']
})
export class ApplayoutmodelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here are the output screens,

After successful loggin in, the firt page is,

[image]

When I click dashboard which is listed inside side nav, the output screen is,

[image]

But what I need even though after clicking dashboard item inside side nav, the dashboard component view should be displayed along with toolbar and side nav button just like in output screen one.

Please help me to solve this issue, I am not getting any ideas.

Comment: If you remove the `*ngIf`, does it show then?

Comment: Yes it does, but it affects the login screen, if i removed it the complete login screen will not be displayed.

Comment: So you need to figure out why `user_id` is being set back to undefined. I suggest adding some console.logs around AppComponent, and see if you can see whats going on

Comment: @user184994 , it got displayed but both views i.e side nav, toolbar and dashboard compoents are getting overlapped. this is the output screen https://ibb.co/bsXgTc

Comment: @Milos Kovacevic, How to separate the login component?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
- in your app.component.html remove ngIf:

```
<div>
    <app-applayoutmodel></app-applayoutmodel>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

- in your app-routing.module.ts you need to put your dashboard component as child component of AppComponent like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'applayout', 
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
        {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is because you want your applayoutmodel component always to be availible even if you click on 'dashboard'. This is where your router-outlet jumps-in: 
he renders your Dashboard component in place of  tag, and preserves applayoutmodel component rendered and intact. Please try this and let me know...