# Angular 4 Side nav and toolbar with content view based on nav item clicked

Tags: angular, routes

I want to have page like this ,

[image]

Please help me, I am not able to find the soluting using angular router

Comment: Are you having any issues in implementing ? If so add code here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. First of all you will need routing module, something like this, lets call it app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';   
import { PageComponent } from './pages/pages.component';
import { Nav1Component} from './components/nav1.component';
import { Nav2Component} from './components/nav2.component';
import { Nav3Component} from './components/nav3.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PageComponent,
      children: [
            { path: 'nav1', component: Nav1Component},
            { path: 'nav2', component: Nav2Component},
            { path: 'nav3', component: Nav3Component}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), NgbModule.forRoot()],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then you need component which will be template component for your app, eg. here you will put all your child components like side bar, toolbar and router-outlet which will represent part of application that will change when you click on one of your nav links! Lets call it PageComponent. Html template of this component will look something like this:

```
<div>
    <ap-toolbar></ap-toolbar> 
    <ap-sidebar></ap-sidebar>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ap-toolbar and ap-sidebar will be components that represent those two parts of your application that you painted red and blue in you example. In your ap-sidebar component, in html template you will have to have links that you can click on with a href that points on nav1, nav2 or nav3. For example:

```
<aside class="left-sidebar">
    <div>
         <nav class="sidebar-nav">
             <ul id="sidebarnav">
                 <li><a href="#" [routerLink]="/nav1">NAV 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" [routerLink]="/nav2">NAV 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" [routerLink]="/nav3">NAV 3</a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>
    </div>
</aside>
```

And that's it! You have everything to finish your example! Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please tell me, where I am going wrong here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077323/nav-toolbar-and-side-nav-not-coming-in-other-components?noredirect=1#comment87171013_50077323

Comment: Hi Anil. Check out my response on that question.

Comment: Hi Milos, I'm not getting the solution , the problem I'm getting here is , when login component appears the toolbar and side NAV should not appear, and after that they should display for every component I will generate

Comment: Your Login component should be totally separated component from AppComponent. So, when you successfully login, you need to redirect user to '/applayout' route so your AppComponent could render. There , in your AppComponent, you have <applayoutmodule> and <router-outlet>.    In your <applayoutmodule> you have routes for /dashboard an /login as i saw. When you click on /dashboard toute, DashboardComponent should render in <router-outlet> with <applayoutmodule> fully rendered! And please let's continue discussion on that particular thread.

Comment: I have commented in that thread with your username, please help me to how to separate the login component?